# How to use the built-in function filter with lambda in Scheme programming?

Tags: scheme

```
"Implement unique, which takes in a list s and returns a new list containing the same elements as s with duplicates removed."

scm> (unique '(1 2 1 3 2 3 1))
(1 2 3)
scm> (unique '(a b c a a b b c))
(a b c)

What I've tried so far is:

(define (unique s)
    (cond
        ((null? s) nil)
        (else (cons (car s)(filter ?)
```

This question required to use the built-in filter function. The general format of filter function is (filter predicate lst), and I was stuck on the predicate part. I am thinking it should be a lambda function. Also, what should I do to solve this question recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(filter predicate list)` returns a new list obtained by eliminating all the elements of the list that does *not* satisfy the predicate. So if you get the first element of the list, to eliminate its duplicates, if they exists, you could simply eliminate from the rest of the list all the elements equal to it, something like:

```
(filter
  (lambda (x) (not (eqv? x (first lst)))) ; what to maintain: all the elements different from (first lst)
  (rest lst))                             ; the list from which to eleminate it
```

for instance:

```
(filter (lambda (x) (not (eqv? x 1))) '(2 1 3 2 1 4))
```

produces `(2 3 2 1 4)`, eliminating all the occurrences of `1`.

Then if you `cons` the first element with the list resulting from the filter, you are sure that there is only a “copy” of that element in the resulting list.

The last step needed to write your function is to repeat recursively this process. In general, when you have to apply a recursive process, you have to find a terminal case, in which the result of the function can be immediately given (as the empty list for lists), and the general case, in which you express the solution assuming that you have already available the function for a “smaller” input (for instance a list with a lesser number of elements).

Consider this definition:

```
define (unique s)
  (if (null? s)
      '()
      (cons (first s)
            (filter
              (lambda (x) (not (eq? x (first s))))
              (unique (rest s))))))
```

`(rest s)` is a list which has shorter than s. So you can apply `unique` to it and find a list without duplicates. If, from this list, you remove the duplicates of the first element with `filter`, and then `cons` this element at the beginning of the result, you have a list without any duplicate.

And this is a possibile solution to your problem.